# how to properly use SimStoreKit

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, storekit

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #define kILSimAllowSimulatedStoreKit 1
    #define ILSimReplaceRealStoreKit 1
    #import <ILSimStoreKit.h>
#else
    #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#endif
```

I am getting an error on ILSimStoreKit.h

I copied all the files from the github into my Project folder

> https://github.com/millenomi/simstorekit

I think I am missing something. I noticed the Header is in < (angle brackets) when user headers are usually in " (quotation marks)

Answer (score 0):

From the [github doc you mentioned in your question](https://github.com/millenomi/simstorekit/blob/master/README.md):

> Where you would import StoreKit, replace:
>
> ```
> #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> #define ILSimReplaceRealStoreKit 1
> #import "ILSimStoreKit.h"
> ```

You need to change the <> with "" in your import line.

Also:

> The library needs to simulate the IAP server using a property list of
>   products, which is set using environment variables (in Xcode, use
>   Project > Edit Active Executable and look in the second tab to set
>   them up). Env variables you can use and the expected format for the
>   products list are documented at the top of ILSimSKPaymentQueue.h.

Comment: Whenever I do that, I get linker errors. Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ILSimDefaultTransactionSimulator", referenced from:
      -[ILSimSKPaymentQueue init] in ILSimSKPaymentQueue.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If I were you I would try reading through the rest of the Readme.md file and go through all of the needed steps. Check out my edit too at the end of my answer, that might help you.